# Ajax script suddenly with no response

Tags: ajax

In the homepage of a site I have the following 2 ajax functions.
Only for some users of the site the first one (loadStaticView) a few days ago suddenly started giving no response, it keeps showing the preload img (the second, loadDynamicView, witch is similar and is called 2 times in the page as the first, is still working).
If these users launch the url called by loadStaticView it works fine, so there should be some problems with the ajax script (maybe in relation to some changes they made in their workstation?).
Any idea?
Thanks in advance

```
function loadStaticView(staticView) {
                try {
                    $('#content'+staticView).html("<div align='center' style='width: 265px;padding-top: 34px; padding-right:30px;padding-bottom: 20px;padding-left:30px;'><img style='vertical-align:middle;' src='/tweb/img/2/ba_loader.gif' align='center'/></div>");
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '/tweb/twebservlet/home/DispatchServlet',
                        dataType: "html",
                        data: {
                            LoadStaticView: "",
                            StaticView: staticView
                        },
                        success:function(dati, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
                            $('#content'+staticView).html("");
                            $('#content'+staticView).html(dati);
                        },
                        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                            $("#dynamicView").html("error");
                        }
                    });

                } catch (err){
                    document.getElementById("dynamicView").html = "error";
                }
            }
```

---

```
        function loadDynamicView(dynamicView, market, data, page) {
            try {
                var dataNow = new Date().getTime();
                $('#content'+dynamicView+market).html("<div align='center' style='width: 265px;padding:52px 30px;'><img style='vertical-align:middle;' src='/tweb/img/2/ba_loader.gif' align='center'/></div>");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/tweb/twebservlet/home/DispatchServlet',
                    dataType: "html",
                    data: {
                        LoadView: "",
                        DynamicView: dynamicView,                        
                        Market: market,
                        View: data,
                        page: page,
                        date: dataNow
                    },
                    success:function(dati, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
                        $('#content'+dynamicView+market).html("");
                        $('#content'+dynamicView+market).html(dati);
                    },
                    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                        $("#dynamicView").html("error");
                    }    
                });

                changeStyle(dynamicView, data, null);

            } catch (err){
                document.getElementById("dynamicView").html = "error";
            }
        }
```

Comment: I also tried $.ajaxSetup({cache: false}); and to put dataNow also in the first script but still no solution

Comment: Can you reproduce the bug? If so, when the error occurs, open the console tab in the browser's inspector. Do you see any error messages there? If so, what message?

Comment: Can you share the url of the webpage?